# How can i use open in new tab in swift ?(WEBKIT)

Tags: swift, webview, wkwebview

How can i use safari-open in new tab in my webkit app

I am creating a internet browser and i need that

Just like the photo
For example, I want to show the open in new tab option when I hold my finger on a link in Google
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pIj4.jpg)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var forwardButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var urlTextField: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    urlTextField.delegate = self
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear( animated )
    let urlString:String = "https://www.google.com"
    let url:URL = URL(string: urlString)!
    let urlRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(urlRequest)
    urlTextField.text = urlString
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let urlString:String = urlTextField.text!
    let url:URL = URL(string: urlString)!
    let urlRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(urlRequest)

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}

@IBAction func backButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if webView.canGoBack {
        webView.goBack()
    }
}
@IBAction func forwardButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if webView.canGoForward {
        webView.goForward()
    }
}
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    backButton.isEnabled = webView.canGoBack
    forwardButton.isEnabled = webView.canGoForward

    urlTextField.text = webView.url?.absoluteString
}
```

}

Comment: please help me i am so confused

Comment: Can you show where you implement the WkWebView Delegate method?

Comment: Yes i add my code right now

Comment: @EkramulHoque Can u help me ?

Comment: yes wait i'm sending you code !

Comment: is it opening new url new page ?? you want open new tab with this url ??

Comment: I want to show the open in new tab option when I hold my finger on a link in Google  @EkramulHoque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this delegate method in bellow you last medhod   :

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
            if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
                let app = UIApplication.shared
                if app.canOpenURL(url) {
                    app.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }
            }
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

is It oky ?